# Maven: Take internal dependency outside of plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency

In the `build` section of one of my `POM`s, I have usage of a plugin in a following way.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
    ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that dependency is declared inside the plugin. For certain reasons, I do not want any dependencies declared in the plugin. I have tried to move the dependency to the `dependencies` section (outside of plugin), but then the dependency is not available to the plugin, and I get an error.

How do I make the dependency available to the plugin without calling it from inside the plugin? Is it even possible?

I tried to add `<scope>runtime</scope>` to the dependency, but still it is not being available.

Comment: What exactely your plugin expected to do ? May be we can do that work by not adding the dependency.

Comment: @Shinchan Dependency was put by someone else. So don't know yet. But if I don't find the solution, that's what I will have to do.